# Rstudio Apache2 reverse proxy sends me back to index.php after sign-in

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up an Apache2 reverse proxy to access another machine at home. I've got the Apache 000-default.conf set up as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
ProxyPreserveHost On

# Servers to proxy the connection, or;
# List of application servers:
# Usage:
# ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
# Example:
ProxyPassMatch ^/rstudio/p/([0-9]+)/(websocket|.*/websocket)/$ ws://192.168.1.2:8787/p/$1/$2/
ProxyPass /rstudio http://192.168.1.2:8787
ProxyPassReverse /rstudio http://192.168.1.2:8787
RedirectMatch permanent ^/rstudio$ /rstudio

ServerName archBox
```

There are two issues:

1. If you browse to the page that is supposed to pass to the RStudio server ([here](http://www.imspatial.me/rstudio)). However, if you browse to the [RStudio sign-in page](http://imspatial.me/rstudio/auth-sign-in) directly, you get the correct page. Why isn't it pulling that page up on its own? If I browse to localhost:8787 on the RStudio machine, the sign-in page is loaded.
2. If I sign in using the sign-in page, after manually typing in the URL, I'm just redirected back to www.imspatial.me. I can't seem to figure out why.

Any ideas?